# .htaccess rewrite problem on language path /en/

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a problem with .htaccess
On localhost it's work its stop on language and redirect good to controler:

```
http://spa.domain.loc/en/about-us.html
```

If i try on online live server, i got 404 because not enter on language condition

```
https://spa.domain.ro/en/rezervare-spa.html
```

I trying to add language after path like this: /en/, but to get the right controller php
I need to have something like this https://spa.domain.ro/rezervare-spa.html?lang=en
i want to know the lang param in php but not see it by the user

```
    RewriteEngine On

# REWRITE IF HAVE LANGUAGE /en/ path
    RewriteBase /

    # Force trailing slash on language code
    RewriteRule ^(en)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

    # Default to Romanian (other languages example path. /en/<anything>)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)
    #RewriteRule !^(en/|/)(.*) %1 [R,L]

    # Route language URLs
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*) $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

# END LANGUAGE

    # Security Fixes
    RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^_scripts/ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^_sql/ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^_logos/ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^etc/live\.2CQA\-VZRG\-6AVL\-PB0Q\-1KJP\.public\.cer$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^etc/live\.2CQA\-VZRG\-6AVL\-PB0Q\-1KJPprivate\.key$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^etc/config\.php$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^etc/config-index\.php$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^etc/config-admin\.php$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^etc/init\.php$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^etc_online/config\.php$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^etc_online/config-index\.php$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^etc_online/config-admin\.php$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^etc_online/init\.php$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^tmp/ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^wpub/\.htaccess$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^wpub/\#wpub$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^\#db/ - [F,L]



    ##### Temporary maintenance ; must be 302 as 307 does not behave correctly (if the file maintenance.html exists in the web root)

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.
    RewriteCond /maintenance.html !-f
    RewriteRule ^maintenance.html$ / [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}            off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^(?:(spa)\.)?(domain\.ro)$

    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


    # Redirect to www if no sub-domain (Ex: http(s)://domain.ext -> http(s)://www.domain.ext)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://spa.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Homepage Rules
    #RewriteCond        %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)\.
    RewriteRule         ^$   index.php?page=frontend.homepage [QSA,L]

    # Custom Rules: old-rules
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/about\.html$                                /about-us.html
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/rates\.php$                                 /rates.html
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/news\.php$                                  /news.html
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/location\.php$                              /location.html
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/gallery\.php$                               /gallery.html
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/privacy-policy\.php$                        /privacy-policy.html
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/contact\.php$                               /contact.html


    # RULES MOBILPAY PAYMENT
        # Custom Rules: return-mobilpay
        RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule         ^return-mobilpay\.html$                                         index.php?page=frontend.mobilpay-return [QSA,L]

        # Custom Rules: confirm-mobilpay
        RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule         ^confirm-mobilpay\.html$                                        index.php?page=frontend.mobilpay-confirm [QSA,L]

    # RULES VIVA WALLET PAYMENT
        # Custom Rules: return-vivawallet
        RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule         ^return-vivawallet\.html$                                       index.php?page=frontend.vivawallet-return [QSA,L]

        # Custom Rules: confirm-vivawallet
        RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule         ^confirm-vivawallet\.html$                                      index.php?page=frontend.vivawallet-confirm [QSA,L]



    # Custom Rules:
    #RewriteCond        %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond        %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule        ^rezervare-bungalow\.html$                                      index.php?page=frontend.rezervare-camera&roomid=3 [QSA,L]

    # Custom Rules:
    RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule         ^offers\.html$                                                  index.php?page=frontend.offers-view [QSA,L]

    ### Sitemap XML Index
    RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule         ^sitemap\.xml$                                                  /index.php?page=frontend.sitemap-sdom-idx [QSA,L]
    ### Sitemap XML Content
    RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule         ^sitemap-content\.xml$                                          /index.php?page=frontend.sitemap-sdom-content [QSA,L]
    ###
    # Custom Rules: backend
    RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule         ^backend.(.*)\.html$                                        admin.php?page=backend\-new.$1 [QSA,L]

    # General rewrite rules: map controller name to something else
    RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule         ^(.*)\.(html|stml|json|xml|rss|csv|txt|png|gif|jpg|pdf|webp)$       index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

    ErrorDocument 400 /index.php?page=frontend.400
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=frontend.404
```

I tested the htaccess it's say it's good... But on my localhost is working and on live server not working..
https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=57608579-efb9-409b-b092-b1936d9ca4a6

Comment: Are you sure `.htaccess` overrides are enabled on the live server? (_Aside:_ The `.htaccess` you shared in the tester is not the same as the file shared here in your question? Some of the rules in your question, notably the canonical redirects are in the wrong order.))

Comment: Yes i found the problem, the hosting live server was with LiteSpeed Apache, and haved alot of [L] conditions so Due to this, this specific flag is working in a different way. URL: https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:troubleshooting:rewrite_difference_on_l_flag_between_lsws_and_apache

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the hosting live server was with LiteSpeed Apache, and haved alot of [L] conditions so Due to this, this specific flag is working in a different way. URL: https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:troubleshooting:rewrite_difference_on_l_flag_between_lsws_and_apache

And new .htaccess is looking like this:

```
# REWRITE IF HAVE LANGUAGE /en/ path
RewriteBase /

# Force trailing slash on language code
RewriteRule ^(en)$ $1/ [R=301]

# Default to Romanian (other languages example path. /en/<anything>)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)
#RewriteRule !^(en/|/)(.*) %1 [R,L]

# Route language URLs
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*) $2?lang=$1 [QSA]
```